# Terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_cast

Tags: c++, image-processing, vector

I have a volume file with pixels of type `uint16_t` that I am trying to read into a buffer for some image processing. I get the error in the title when I execute the following code

```
int main() {
    using data_type = uint16_t;

    std::basic_ifstream<data_type> file_in{
        "test.vol",
        std::ifstream::binary
    };
    std::vector<data_type> FileBuffer{
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>(file_in),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>()
    };
```

When I try to debug in gdb its not really giving me much info. I used some print statements to narrow down the bug to the Filebuffer section, but I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Whole program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "beginning of main" << std::endl;
    using data_type = uint16_t;
    std::cout << "after using data type" << std::endl;

    std::basic_ifstream<data_type> file_in{
        "test.vol",
        std::ifstream::binary
    };
    std::cout << "after ifstream " << std::endl;
    std::vector<data_type> FileBuffer{
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>(file_in),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<data_type>()  // end of stream iterator
    };

    std::cout << "after filebuffer" << std::endl;

    size_t height = 640;
    size_t width = 512;
    size_t sliceSize = height * width * 2;
    size_t sliceCount = FileBuffer.size() / sliceSize;

    size_t newHeight = height - 20;
    size_t newWidth = width - 92;
    size_t newSliceSize = newHeight * newWidth * 2;
    size_t newImageSize = newSliceSize * sliceCount;

    std::vector<data_type> NewFileBuffer(newImageSize);

    auto it_buffer = FileBuffer.begin();
    auto it_new_buffer = NewFileBuffer.begin();

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sliceCount; i++) {
        auto it_line = it_buffer + 20 * width;  // skip 20 first lines
        // auto it_line = it_buffer;            // skip last 20 lines

        for (size_t j = 0; j < newHeight; j++) {
            auto it_column = it_line + 46;

            it_new_buffer = std::copy(
                it_column,
                it_column + newWidth,
                it_new_buffer
            );

            it_line += width; // goto next line
        }
        it_buffer += sliceSize; // goto next slice
    }
    std::basic_ofstream<data_type> file_out{
        "test2.vol",
        std::ofstream::binary
    };
    std::copy(
        NewFileBuffer.begin(),
        NewFileBuffer.end(),
 std::ostreambuf_iterator<data_type>(file_out)
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2d282838635c2ad), sorry.

Comment: I can post the whole code to get it to compile if you'd like

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You forgot `#include <fstream>`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77609bbddedde800

Comment: @user2990406 You're supposed to post a [MCVE], that's enough.

Comment: @NathanOliver No repro though?

Comment: @user2990406 That misses the **minimal** point now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well you have to read a file. You cannot do that with coliru.

Comment: @NathanOliver There are tricks how you can, but well.

Comment: What happens if you use a `std::istream_iterator` instead of a `std::istreambuf_iterator`?

Comment: @NathanOliver How would I implement that?

Comment: @user2990406 You remove the `buf` between `istream` and `_iterator`. (I'm not joking)

Comment: I cannot really reproduce this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d4e0d26ba0c38ef Do you `#include <iterator>`?

Comment: yeah im including iterator and when i remove buf I get this error  `error: no matching function for call to std::istream_iterator<short unsigned int>::istream_iterator(std::basic_ifstream<short unsigned int>&)’
  std::istream_iterator<data_type>(file_in)`

Comment: I am compling this on c++ 11 on linux if that helps at all. could it have something to do with my actual volume file?

Comment: @user2990406 Can you `#include <iterator>`?

Comment: @NathanOliver yeah

Comment: @user2990406 Did it work after you included `<iterator>`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I've been including iterator the whole time (look at the full code I posted)

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like `istream_iterator` expects a `char` stream and not a `short unsigned int`.  What happens if you make `file_in` a normal stream opened in binary mode but read it into the vector using a `std::istream_iterator`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125718/discussion-between-user2990406-and-nathanoliver).